# Summing Divisors with While Loop and If Statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

Beginner here. I tried to sum all divisors of a number but the number itself. I wrote a code without using `elif`.

```
def sum_divisors(n):
sum = 0
divisor = 1

while divisor < n:
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        n % divisor == 0
        sum += divisor
        divisor += 1

return sum

print(sum_divisors(0))
# 0
print(sum_divisors(3))  # Should sum of 1
# 1
print(sum_divisors(36))  # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18
# 55
print(sum_divisors(102))  # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51
# 114
```

I got the answers 0, 1, 630 and 5151. Then, I rewrote the code by using elif. Got the right answers.

```
    def sum_divisors(n):
sum = 0
divisor = 1

while divisor < n:
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n % divisor == 0:
        sum += divisor
        divisor += 1
    else:
        divisor += 1

return sum

print(sum_divisors(0))
print(sum_divisors(3))
print(sum_divisors(36))
print(sum_divisors(102))
```

There is something wrong in the first attempt, I feel it but I can't explain it. Is it related to the order of operations? Can someone explain what's going on in the execution of the first code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared a statement with no usage `n % divisor == 0` And in the second code block it is an `elif` statement. That's why the first code is not working - you have checked whether it is `True` but you did not add an `elif` statement and what should be executed there.

Comment: So even the `n % divisor == 0` statement is false, execution moved on?

Comment: @Meer75 yes, because you did not used the `if` or `elif` statement. If you want to program do not execute if that is `False` you have to add such a statement.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def sum_divisors(n):
    sum1 = 0
    divisor = 1
    while divisor < n:
        if n == 0:
            return 0
        elif n % divisor == 0:
            sum1 += divisor
            divisor += 1
        else:
            divisor += 1
    return sum1

print(sum_divisors(36))
print(sum_divisors(102))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).